# Record system list of customers each with list of cars

Tags: list, class, inheritance

I am working on a simple simulation for a mechanic record system where it will contain a list of customers and their details; each having a list of cars which they own. Every visit will also be recorded.

Customer: Name, address, list of cars (with make, model and reg number)

Visit: Date, Owner, Car, Description on work done, Date of next visit

In the main method i need to simulate the creation of two clients with each having 5 cars each. The data will be hard coded. Then need to add 7 visit and display all info.

```
class Human 
{

    int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private string address;

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }
}

class Customer : Human
{
    public LinkedList<Car> Cars = new LinkedList<Car>();

   public Customer()
   {

   }


 }

 public class Visit
{


    public int visitId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeVisited { get; set; }
    public string customer { get; set; }
    public string Discussion { get; set; }

    public DateTime NextDateTimetoVisit { get; set; }

}

 class Mechanic :Human
{

    public LinkedList<Customer> customerDetails;

    public LinkedList<Visit> visitDetails;

    public LinkedList<Car> carDetails;

    public Mechanic()
    {
        customerDetails = new LinkedList<Customer>();

        visitDetails = new LinkedList<Visit>();

        carDetails = new LinkedList<Car>();

    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer c)
    {

        customerDetails.AddLast(c);
    }

    public void AddVisit(Visit v)
    {

        visitDetails.AddLast(v);
    }



    public LinkedList<Customer> ViewCustomer()
    {

          return customerDetails;
    }

     public LinkedList<Visit> ViewVisit()
    {

        return visitDetails;
    }


     public void AddCar(Car car)
     {

         carDetails.AddLast(car);
     }


}
```

//Main

```
 //Create customer
                    Customer customer1 = new Customer();
                    Customer customer2 = new Customer();

                    customer1.Id = 1;
                    customer1.Name = "Brandon Spiteri";
                    customer1.Address = "22, St. George's St. B'bugia";

                    mech1.AddCustomer(customer1);

                    Car car1 = new Car();

                    car1.carmake = "Hyundai";
                    car1.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car1.carregnum = "BAH 864";
                    car1.Id = 1; //check

                    mech1.AddCar(car1);


                    //mech1.AddCar(car1);

                    Car car2 = new Car();

                    car2.carmake = "Citroen";
                    car2.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car2.carregnum = "IBE 554";
                    car2.Id = 1;
                    mech1.AddCar(car2);

                    Car car3 = new Car();


                    car3.carmake = "Toyota";
                    car3.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car3.carregnum = "DAP 691";
                    car3.Id = 1;
                    mech1.AddCar(car3);

                    Car car4 = new Car();

                    car4.carmake = "Nissan";
                    car4.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car4.carregnum = "EBD 482";
                    car4.Id = 1;
                    mech1.AddCar(car4);

                    Car car5 = new Car();

                    car5.carmake = "Rover";
                    car5.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car5.carregnum = "BAD 505";
                    car5.Id = 1;
                    mech1.AddCar(car5);




                    customer2.Id = 2;
                    customer2.Name = "George Spiteri";
                    customer2.Address = "6, Dun A. Gambin St. Santa Lucija";

                    mech1.AddCustomer(customer2);

                    Car car6 = new Car();

                    car6.carmake = "Mercedes";
                    car6.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car6.carregnum = "BAH 864";
                    car6.Id = 2;
                    mech1.AddCar(car6);

                    Car car7 = new Car();

                    car7.carmake = "BMW";
                    car7.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car7.carregnum = "EFG 426";
                    car7.Id = 2;
                    mech1.AddCar(car7);

                    Car car8 = new Car();

                    car8.carmake = "Peugeot";
                    car8.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car8.carregnum = "IHJ 376";
                    car8.Id = 2;
                    mech1.AddCar(car8);

                    Car car9 = new Car();

                    car9.carmake = "Mazda";
                    car9.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car9.carregnum = "ADL 693";
                    car9.Id = 2;
                    mech1.AddCar(car9);

                    Car car10 = new Car();

                    car10.carmake = "Ford";
                    car10.carmodelnum = "HJ30NAEJJ";
                    car10.carregnum = "RGJ 486";
                    car10.Id = 2;
                    mech1.AddCar(car10);
```

When I debug to see if the cars are under the particular customer, they seem to be declared separately and the customers have no cars. Also is the Visit class implemented correctly? Where am i going wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move all lists as well as the method AddCar to the base class like this:

```
class Human 
{
 public LinkedList<Customer> customerDetails;

 public LinkedList<Visit> visitDetails;

 public LinkedList<Car> carDetails;

 public void AddCar(Car car)
 {

     carDetails.AddLast(car);
 }
 ...
}

class Customer:public Human
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: that was because I experimented with changing inheritance of classes and using customer1.AddCar(car5); instead of mech1.AddCar(car5); but none of them worked out.

Comment: Ok, now I see it: you need to remove public void AddCar(Car car) from Mechanic into the base class Human! Otherwise has Customer no such method!

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did as you told me but I am getting an error at the statement: carDetails.AddLast(car); in  the method of: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Is there anything I need to add?

Comment: Have you created the new car like: Car car1 = new Car(); before you try to add it?

Comment: Yes I am creating the instance in the main as posted above.. I made class Car inherit from class Customer. I tried linking them together with car1.Id = 1; is it a good idea?

Comment: I fear that is no good idea, finally is car not a Human huh? ;) I wish you happy proggen - you will get it!